# Histogram in Python in functional way in O(n)

Tags: python, functional-programming

Not sure how to formulate question properly, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Say I want to make histogram in functional way in pure Python.

```
def add_value(bins, x):
    i = int(x // 10)
    return (*bins[:i], bins[i] + 1, bins[i + 1:])

def histogram(data):
    return reduce(data, add_value, (0,) * 10)
```

It's O(n^2), right? Is it possible somehow to optimize it to O(n)?

I'm tempted to change tuple to list:

```
def add_value(bins, x):
    bins[int(x // 10)] += 1
    return bins

def histogram(data):
    return reduce(data, add_value, [0] * 10)
```

But I don't feel confident about mixing mutable lists and functional style that imply immutability. Are there any dangerous pitfall connected to this? I haven't found any.

I'm asking about merely technical problems, not something ideological or opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying I'm still learning my way around functional programming myself, so I'm no expert.

To answer your first question, yes, I agree that your functional implementation is O(n^2), as you are rebuilding the entire tuple at each step.

For your second question, here is a functional implementation of histogram in Python which I believe to be O(n):

```
from itertools import groupby

def histogram(data):
    return dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], sum(1 for i in x[1])), groupby(data, lambda x: x // 10)))
```

It doesn't look much like your original program, and the histogram is returned as a dictionary instead of a list. If you want an immutable result, call tuple instead of dict. Or just leave it as a map result.

You might think it's not very readable, and I would tend to agree. As much as I love Python, it's not the best language for functional programming. Not terrible, but not the best. Idiomatic Python tends to discourage the use of map, reduce etc. A Pythonic histogram implementation would initialize an empty list or hash, and iterate over the data in a plain old for loop. But I'm digressing.

To make the implementation a little clearer, take a look at this equivalent implementation in Ruby. I picked Ruby because it's pretty close to Python, but slightly more biased towards functional programming. Functional code in Ruby tends to be more readable than in Python.

```
def histogram(data)
    data.group_by { |i| i / 10 }.map { |b, values| [b, values.length] }.to_h
end
```

As for "dangerous pitfalls" and "technical problems": in the case of single threaded execution, there is no problem using mutable data structures in functional programs.

But, imagine that your histogram calculation was to run on a large data set, using multiple CPU cores or even a cluster of CPUs. The input data is broken up into chunks, and your `add_value` function is executed concurrently in multiple threads of execution.

If all the threads operate on a shared mutable list, two threads can modify an element in your `bins` list at the same time, like this:

1. Thread A reads a value from `data`. Let's say, 33. 33 // 10 == 3
2. Thread B reads a value from `data`. Let's say, 36. 36 // 10 == 3
3. Thread A reads `bins[3] == 100`.
4. Thread B also reads `bins[3] == 100`.
5. Thread A calculates `100 + 1`, and writes `hist[3] = 101`.
6. Thread B calculates `100 + 1`, and writes `hist[3] = 101`. Uh oh.

To prevent this, you could create or use an existing data structure with built in locking mechanisms. These have a performance cost though, which may become a bottleneck as you use more threads.

If you used functional code and immutable data structures, you wouldn't have to manage concurrent access to shared data. Instead, each thread independently calculates a partial histogram. Then, these partial histograms would be merged by reduction into a single result. Merging histograms would be done by simply "adding them together".

I hope that makes things clearer and answers your questions.

Comment: `groupby` does the trick. Shame on me, never used this function. Also, `sum(1 for i in x[1])` looks interesting: not sure if `x[1]` is iterator but it looks elegant. I learned couple of interesting things. My original task is to calculate several statistics, histogram is just simple example in this case. But, at least, someone else thought about this problem; I'm now more confident that I didn't miss something trivial. Thanks!

Comment: `x[1]` is a special type of object returned by `group_by`. It doesn't respond to `len`, so the `sum` is to calculate the length. As a workaround, it's not bad, but the ruby version feels more readable.

Comment: `sum(1 for i in x[1])` -- this seems needless. I think `groupby` has a `size()` method.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm pretty sure it's necessary. I don't think the result of groupby has a size method.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned, doing this in FP style is not ideal in Python. I'd first like to propose a variation on @bsa's approach, which is somewhat more readable, though:

```
def histo(sorted_data):
    return {bin: sum(1 for v in values) for bin, values in groupby(sorted_data)}
```

This at least replaces the function calls with a dictionary comprehension and is probably the most readable solution, taken aside the `sum` trick for the group length.

On the other hand, here's how I would implement your first approach in a language having pattern matching and linked lists (acting as if list consing in Python were O(1)):

```
def histo2(sorted_data, bins=[]):
    if sorted_data == []:
        return bins

    x, *xs = sorted_data

    if bins == []:
        return histo2(xs, [(x, 1)])

    *init, (v, n) = bins

    if v == x:
        return histo2(xs, init + [(x, n+1)])
    else:
        return histo2(xs, bins + [(x, 1)])
```

(It could also be done as a fold/`reduce`, but that just makes it harder to read.)

This at least should illustrate how such things are done in, e.g., Haskell. In principle, you could take a linked list type Python and just plug it in here. Also, it is tail recursive, which could get optimized out if the compiler supported it.

And since @bsa also comments on parallelization: histograms are the classic ideal [map-reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce#Examples) example. One could also try to implement the above version in that style.

(Side note: `int(x // 10)` is redundant, since the `//` operator already performs integer division.)

Comment: I like the dictionary comprehension, agreed that it's more readable. To be equivalent, you could include the binning using a list comprehension: `return {bin: sum(1 for v in values) for bin, values in groupby([x//10 for x in data])}`

Comment: Or better.. a generator (just learned this syntax!) `return {bin: sum(1 for v in values) for bin, values in groupby(x//10 for x in data)}`